# Cannot remove gerrit trigger server from jenkins

Tags: triggers, gerrit

Added a gerrit trigger plugin in the jenkins. While setting up a gerrit server within the gerrit trigger configuration, I cannot remove the server already configured. It simply says

```
Cannot remove the last server!
```

But I can edit the server details. Anyone has faced this issue?

```
Jenkins ver. 1.653
gerrit trigger version  2.21.1
```

I dont have any job configured with Gerrit Trigger, and this jenkins is a fresh instance. Just have a test job

Answer (score 3):

There are must be some error in that gerrit server config section.

You can shutdown the tomcat if your jenkins was hold by tomcat, or shutdown the jenkins what ever.

Then goto `/home/$yourname/.jenkins` , edit `gerrit-trigger.xml` remove the server section. then restart jenkins and check it.

I just found it works.

Comment: thats like taking a chance. Will try in the test server

Answer (score 0):

By the words what I understand is that I cannot remove the last, the final server. That means there should be at least one server configured, I cannot remove all of them. If you want to remove this, you have to create one more and delete the older one.

But not sure why it is so